# Oracleで特定のcolumnに属する値の戻り値を空白文字にしたい

Tags: sql, oracle

初歩的な質問となりますが、SQLで下記のような結果を得たい場合どういった構文が考えられるでしょうか？

No　Name　Address　Tel
1　　test　　　　　　+81
2　　hoge　　　　　　+81
3　　hoge　　　　　　+81

Addressにも本来であれば値が入力されていますが、column自体は残して値だけ空文字へ置き換えて結果を求めたいです。

何かいい手段があればご教授ください。

Answer (score 1):

あなたのご質問を読む限りでは、

```
SELECT No, Name, '' AS Address, Tel FROM the_table;
```

のように書けば良いように思われます。何かこれではダメと言ったことがあればお知らせください。